# How can make multiple paint object?

Tags: java, android

I want to draw multiple circles as much as number I entered.
but I don't know how to create objects of any number.
I just know the following method.
`Paint circle1 = new Paint();`
`Paint circle2 = new Paint();`
`...`

How can make multiple paint object?

+
OMG You guys are so friendly!
I got really impressed. Thank you so much!

Comment: have you tried to create an array of circles? are you familiar with loops?

Comment: @FuzzyAmi sorry, I don't know how to create an array of circles. I only learn about simple array like integer array..

Comment: Well the way you created integer array the same way you can create Paint array by specifying Data Type to be Paint instead of int , Look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for creating multiple `Paint` objects. Only you need an array of colors for your circles and also an array of their positions and radius.

Do this in `onDraw` method of your `View`

```
     private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
     @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i<n ;i++){
               mPaint.setColor(color);
               canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,radius,mPaint);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you! it works and I can draw multiple circle!! it's paradigm shift! OMG really thank you XD

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for/while` loop to get the required number of objects you need and use an `ArrayList` to store the newly created Objects -

```
List<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
for(int i=0; i<numberYouEntered; i++){

  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paints.add(paint);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answers are easier to understand in my level!

Answer (score 0):

Try array Of Paints

```
final int MAX_NUM=10;// Specify whatever number you want
Paint[] circle=new Paint[MAX_NUM];
for(int i=0;i<MAX_NUM;i++){
    circle[i]=new Paint();
    circle[i].setColor(color);
    //specify other attributes
}
```

Comment: Creating array of  `Paint` is not a best way it's better to store colors in an integer array